# rawQuery in Android not showing database contents

Tags: android, sqlite

Yes, this is homework but I did my due diligence and I am stuck! Hopefully somebody can help!

I am having problems with my rawQuery. It is not showing anything. I am pretty sure that the database is not empty because I added a couple of insert statements for testing (and I also tried it with `put()` and `insert()`) and, still, nothing showed up.

The problem is, when I run my code, I don't get any errors or exception but it never enters the while loop in logDatabase (`while !c.moveToNext`).

I have done a fair amount of research but all of the books that I look at seem to tell me to do it this way. Perhaps I am missing something obvious but I can't for the life of my figure out what it is. Thanks!

```
package jschuler.cs211d.hw06b;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.*;
    import android.widget.*;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import android.content.*;
    import android.database.*;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

    public class play extends Activity 
                      implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener
    {    
        private static final String DBNAME = "statesDB";
        static final String STATE = "state", CAPITAL = "capital";

    //*****************************onCreate()*****************************
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.play);

            // Check to see if SD card is available. If not, warn the user
            if(!sdCardAvailable())
            {
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "No SD card available.", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "SD card is available.", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();
            }

            loadDB();
        }
    //**************************onCheckChanged()**************************
    //  Set the variable that represents the type, depending on 
    //  what the user has selected in the radio group.    
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup g, int CheckedId)
        {

        }
    //******************************loadDB()******************************
    //  Create the data structures to hold the data
        public void loadDB()
        {
            SQLiteDatabase db;
            db = openOrCreateDatabase("statesDB", 
                SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);

            db.setVersion(1);
            db.setLockingEnabled(true);

            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists states(_id integer primary key autoincrement, STATE text, CAPITAL text);");

            Scanner sc;

            try
            {
                File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath());
                File f = new File(dir, "US_states");
                sc = new Scanner(f);

                // Skip the first line
                sc.nextLine();
                sc.nextLine();

                // Read in the names of the states and capitals. 
                while(sc.hasNextLine())
                {
                    String[] nextItem = sc.nextLine().split("\\s{2,}");
                    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                    cv.put(STATE, nextItem[0]);
                    db.insert("states", STATE, cv);
                    cv.put(CAPITAL, nextItem[1]);
                    db.insert("states", CAPITAL, cv);
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Error loading data.", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();
            }

            db.close();

            logDatabase();
        }
    //***************************logDatabase()****************************
        public void logDatabase()
        {
            SQLiteDatabase db;
            db = openOrCreateDatabase("statesDB", 
                SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);

            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO states (STATE) values ('AB');");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO states (STATE) values ('CD');");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO states (STATE) values ('EF');");

            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(STATE, "AB");
            db.insert("states", STATE, cv);

            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT STATE, CAPITAL FROM states",null);

            while(!c.moveToNext())
            {
                Log.d("mtn","in moveToNext()");
                Log.d("state",c.getString(0));
                Log.d("capital",c.getString(1));
            }

            db.close();
        }
    //*************************sdCardAvailable()**************************
    //  Determine whether there is an SD card available and if it is 
    //  writable.
        public boolean sdCardAvailable()
        {
            boolean storageAvailable = false;
            boolean storageWritable = false;

            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

            if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
            {
                storageAvailable = storageWritable = true;
            }
            else if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state))
            {
                storageAvailable = true;
                storageWritable = false;
            }
            else
            {
                storageAvailable = storageWritable = false;
            }

            return (storageWritable && storageAvailable);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while(!c.moveToNext())
```

This line, translated to english, becomes "While you **can't** move to the next item, enter the loop, exit otherwise".

Comment: I understand this but my teacher specifically said to use !c.moveToNext and several books have said exactly the same thing. 
But...other books and sites have said the opposite. 

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToNext%28%29

Comment: There's no way to enter the loop when there's data in the cursor.  If you *do* enter the loop, that means there's no data to print to log output.

Comment: [The documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToNext%28%29) also seems to indicate the the ! is necessary.

But when I use c.moveToNext and remove the third Log.d (I get an error which, I believe, is related to my loadDB method), I get an infinite loop. This leads me to believe that it DOES need to be moveToNext but when I do that, the loop is not entered.

Comment: Following the link you provided, I don't see any mention of using a ! operator when calling c.moveToNext.  Did you link to the right page?

Comment: I believe so. It doesn't say anything about not using the ! but it says that "This method will return false if the cursor is already past the last entry in the result set."

So, it makes sense that you would use !moveToNext but it appears that it will never enter the loop that way.

I took out the ! and it seemed to work but I am not sure exactly why my teacher (and a couple of books) suggested using the !. 

If you have any idea why they would suggest that, I would be interested to hear!

Comment: I have no idea why it would suggest that-  What I was saying before, the reason it never enters the loop:  If there's still data left, and you're not past the end of the loop, !moveToNext evaluates to "not (true)", essentially false, so it skips the loop if there's data.  If there's no data left, it evalutes to "not (false)", essentially true, and enters the loop.

Comment: That's what I thought. Weird. I will have to ask him again because I am confused! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See this code and try to write your program in this fashion i am sure it will work....

```
import android.content.ContentValues;

import android.content.Context;

import android.database.Cursor;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class TimeListDatabaseHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "timetracker.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "timerecords";


    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_TIME = "note";
    public static final String COLUMN_NOTE = "time";


    private TimeTrackerOpenHelper openHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;


    TimeListDatabaseHelper(Context context) {

        openHelper = new TimeTrackerOpenHelper(context);
        database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();


    }

    public void saveTimeRecord(String time, String notes) {

        ContentValues contentValue = new ContentValues();

        contentValue.put(COLUMN_TIME, time);
        contentValue.put(COLUMN_NOTE, notes);

        database.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null, contentValue);




        }



    public Cursor getAllTimeRecords() {
        return database.rawQuery(
        "select * from " + DATABASE_TABLE,
        null
        );
        }


public class TimeTrackerOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public TimeTrackerOpenHelper(Context context) {

        super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null , DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+DATABASE_TABLE+"("+COLUMN_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT "+","+COLUMN_TIME+" TEXT "+","+COLUMN_NOTE+" NOTE"+")");



    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

                   db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ DATABASE_TABLE);
                   onCreate(db);

    }

}

}
```

Now what u need is to create an instance of this class in the main activity, and pass the Activity (ie "this") into this class constructor. Then using the reference of this class in the main activity, try to get the data from this class..

eg:

```
In main activity class

   TimeListDatabaseHelper db = new TimeListDatabaseHelper(this);
    db.getAllTimeRecords();
```

Comment: This is definitely good to know about but I do not think that my professor will accept that. He wants us to use the methods that he described in class. 

If I can't get it to work otherwise I will do this though, because it's better to have a working program that not!

Thanks!

Comment: dear try to look carefully, both work nearly same, but with different method names, and different placement of code.... try to figure out the logic behind my program,and then implement it in the way your teachers wants with his methods.

Comment: Good advice. I got it working but I will definitely look back at this after I get my other project finished!! I appreciate the help. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

the fact that you add an insert doesn't mean it will get inserted into the database. here is a reference [Android Insert statement](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) ... to make sure your database is populated, open your DDMS, then on the Devices make sure you have selected your emulator, then click on the file explorer > Data > Data >    and then pull the database and open it with a database manager program and run a select query and make sure it has data in it.

and as @Alexander Lucas said, your code is making it not enter the loop since you are putting the " ! " in  `while(!c.moveToNext())` so, try replacing for  `while(c.moveToNext())`

Comment: Thank you for the link! Also, this DDMS thing is awesome. It will be extremely helpful. But...I am not sure how to open the database file. I took a mySQL class but we didn't open any databases other than the ones that we created.

I did open it in TextEdit and it is garbled but I can see that I have added things multiple times, which explains the "infinite loop" that I mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: I should have Googled before posting. I found SQLite Database Browser on the SourceForge website. This and DDMS should help me out a lot! Thank you!